# Get youtube video link in python

Tags: python, search, hyperlink, youtube

I need to make sure that I enter a word in the console, and a link to the video should be displayed for me, for example, if I mean the word Linkin Park in the console, it should give me a link to the first video for this request. In my example, the first link is Numb [Official Music Video] - Linkin Park

How can i do this?

Comment: You can use **pytube** library. See [the document on pytube Search](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/search.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will resolve your query.

```py
def search_video(self,query):
    search_query = query.split()

    url = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

    for word in search_query:
        url += word + "+"

    time.sleep(1)
    webbrowser.open_new(url[:-1])  
    #-1 is used here, because in the URL we have an added + at the end.
```

UPDATE: You can use `Selenium`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

search_query = input().split()
print(search_query)

for word in search_query:
    final_query += word + "+"
    
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}'.format(final_query))
select = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail')
link += [select.get_attribute('href')]
print(link)
```

Comment: thanks, but this is a bit different, it gives me a link to a list of videos, and I need a link to the very first video from this list.

Comment: Check the updated code @Ikrom